# Correlation matrix of rows, correcting for correlation matrix of columns

Tags: correlation, covariance, independence, covariance-matrix

Given a matrix of observations (rows) x variables (columns), can we compute the correlation matrix of the rows, but corrected by the correlation matrix of the columns?  The goal would be to avoid inflation in the correlation p values, since the t-test for Pearson correlation assumes that the columns/variables are uncorrelated, independent observations, i.e. that the correlation matrix of the columns is the identity matrix.

Intuitively, this could be accomplished with a weighted correlation, where e.g. if a pair of variables are nearly perfectly correlated, they would each be down-weighted by a factor of 2.

Edit: there is an [exact null distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Using_the_exact_distribution) for the correlations in the case where the columns are independent, but there are only two rows and this pair of rows is sampled from a bivariate normal distribution.  I would like a null distribution for the opposite case, where the rows are independent, but the columns are sampled from a multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: Can you explain symbolically the assumption you're referring to (made by the t-test for Pearson correlation)?

Comment: @eric_kernfeld: The assumption is that $t = r \sqrt{\frac{n - 2}{1 - r^2}}$ is t-distributed with $n - 2$ degrees of freedom under the null, where $r$ is the correlation and $n$ is the number of data points.

Comment: That's not what I meant to ask for. When you write "assumes that the columns/variables are independent", can you write out what that means to you and how it differs from the model you have in mind?

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit ambiguous - I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something you can try.

Let $X$ be your data matrix. Normalize $X$ as you choose.

Calculate the $p \times p$ correlation matrix $M$ for the columns of $X$.

Then write the singular value decomposition of $M$ as 
$$USV^T = M.$$
Define a new data set $$Y = X U \sqrt{S} .$$

Then calculate the correlation matrix for the rows of $Y$.

This is in some sense what you are after: the "adjusted" correlation matrix for the rows of $X$.

Comment: If I understand correctly, without the $\sqrt{S}$ this would be PCA, but the $\sqrt{S}$ additionally weights by the square root of the percent of variance explained by each component.  One desirable property of a solution is that if you duplicate a column of the data matrix $X$ (say with a bit of noise), the correlation p values should stay the same. Here, I think you'd have the same top principal components, but the PCs most similar to the duplicated column would have larger eigenvalues, which would change the correlation p values.

Comment: Not sure what the question here is.  I provided a real example in the edit.  Play around with it.

Comment: I was saying I think it's not robust because if you duplicate one of the columns, the p values change.  I think all SVD-based solutions have this problem.

Comment: I'm curious whether you could instead use $Y = XU$ (PCA) or $Y = XSU$ (PCA weighted by % variance explained) rather than $Y = X\sqrt{S}U$ (PCA weighted by sqrt of % variance explained)?

Comment: @1'' Hey sorry I had a typo in the answer, the multiplication order should be switched.

Comment: No problem :)  What do you think of the robustness issue I mentioned?  Also, any particular reason why it's a square root?